# How Yii 2 get and use salt and cost to verify the password hash during the login process?

Tags: php, yii, passwords, yii2, password-hash

I try to understand the login process of Yii framework 2. I am stuck at the moment when the `Security` class validates the password with the following line of code.

```
return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
```

When I view this `validatePassword()` method, it looks like following.

```
public function validatePassword($password, $hash)
{
    if (!is_string($password) || $password === '') {
        throw new InvalidParamException('Password must be a string and cannot be empty.');
    }

    if (!preg_match('/^\$2[axy]\$(\d\d)\$[\.\/0-9A-Za-z]{22}/', $hash, $matches) || $matches[1] < 4 || $matches[1] > 30) {
        throw new InvalidParamException('Hash is invalid.');
    }

    switch ($this->passwordHashStrategy) {
        case 'password_hash':
            if (!function_exists('password_verify')) {
                throw new InvalidConfigException('Password hash key strategy "password_hash" requires PHP >= 5.5.0, either upgrade your environment or use another strategy.');
            }
            return password_verify($password, $hash);
        case 'crypt':
            $test = crypt($password, $hash);
            $n = strlen($test);
            if ($n !== 60) {
                return false;
            }
            return $this->compareString($test, $hash);
        default:
            throw new InvalidConfigException("Unknown password hash strategy '{$this->passwordHashStrategy}'");
    }
}
```

And when I view the `compareString()` method, it looks like following.

```
public function compareString($expected, $actual)
{
    $expected .= "\0";
    $actual .= "\0";
    $expectedLength = StringHelper::byteLength($expected);
    $actualLength = StringHelper::byteLength($actual);
    $diff = $expectedLength - $actualLength;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $actualLength; $i++) {
        $diff |= (ord($actual[$i]) ^ ord($expected[$i % $expectedLength]));
    }
    return $diff === 0;
}
```

I could not understand how Yii 2 gets and uses the salt and cost to verify and compare the password with the password hash? Does any senior developer know and could you please explain me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By default, Yii2 use `password_hash` to store and validate password. Salt and cost included automatically in password_hash algorithms, we don't  care.

```
password_verify($password, $hash);
```

Refer : http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php

Comment: In case I want to use a custom salt and cost. How can I do that? It is because I have a separate application which will create the password hash and I want Yii application to use the salt and cost of that separate application to log the user in. This means that Yii application will not create the password hash, neither the salt of any password hash but only log the user in.

Comment: are you converting an old system to yii2 and want to retain the user list (login without change password) ?

Comment: No, I have two applications, the first one is developed with a CMS and the second one is developed with Yii 2. The one with CMS creates the user account, but the one with Yii 2 will use that account to log the user in.

Comment: Very simple, do not use Yii::$app->security->validatePassword, use your custom validatePassword function from CMS.

Comment: I have the same problem, I have two applications, one in nodejs and second in Yii2, both are using same database. but I can't validate password in nodejs which is encrypted by yii.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your own class from yii\base\Security class, redefine parent methods generateSalt(), generatePasswordHash(), validatePassword() and set your new Security class in Yii app:

```
 'components' => [
   ...
    'security' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\MySecurity'
    ],
```